# Is it ok to include other frameworks or libraries in my framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks

**Background:** I am about to start preparing my 1st framework for my clients, so they can easily integrate it into their apps and fetch data from my servers without dealing how communication with server is working. I chose `ASIHTTPRequest` library for communication.

**Question:** how should I deal with `ASIHTTPRequest` or any other static library - make it a part of my framework or let adopters link against it themselves in their projects?

I'm opting to make it a part of my framework, so I can prevent users from setting breakpoints in `ASIHTTPRequest` and easily access/log connection frames/data. But what would happen if my clients will need this library for their own purposes? Will they be able to link it second time? Won't it cause any run-time collisions?

Sorry for wording... Please let me stand corrected if I'm confusing any terms :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different types of frameworks to consider, so I would do two things:

1. For any third party library like ASI that you use, include a
   directory with the source as deanWombonurne indicated.  Make sure to indicate which version of the library you have included if it is not clear (add a VERSION) file if needed or name the directory).
2. For Apple frameworks, include a manifest file somewhere that gives a
   list of all the Apple frameworks they should include in their
   project to satisfy your framework requirements.

Comment: so it's better to make all 3rd party frameworks external to my framework and ask my users to include them in their projects? This way both my framework and their project will be able to use these 3rd party frameworks? And if I compile in 3rd party software into my bundle's executable, they won't be able to use frameworks already included by me? See also my comment to Dean's answer. Thank you :) For now I think I'll dive into Bundle and Framework Programming Guides by Apple.

Comment: It's always better to expose what libraries you are using, so that the users of your library know not to add it again - if you just had it embedded in yours and someone added ASI (which is incredibly likely) the symbols would conflict with the ones in your library at link time.  Also including it more visibly allows the user of your framework to choose to upgrade to a later version, at risk of compatibility but it may give them a feature they really need.  If you were REALLY kind, you'd also ship a set of unit tests that would verify features of the third party library you rely on still work.

Comment: Thank you Kendall for your thorough response - it helped me a lot.  SO community is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Look at how ASIHTTPRequest handle it :)

They make you link against lots of the iOS frameworks but they don't ship them with their download.

However, they do ship code for Reachability with their library - if you don't already have it then you can include it. If you already have it in your project then that's OK too.

I would ship the source of ASI in a seperate folder - then your users can either include it or not.

That also has the benefit of ensuring that the version of ASI they use will work with your library ;)

(see the ASI [docs here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions))

Comment: I think I got your idea, however I'd like to do something opposite - hide the sources of my framework (i.e. prepare a framework bundle that has Versions and Headers dirs inside plus dynamic shared library). That way I think I'll prevent setting breakpoints in ASI as it will be contained in executable. I think your point is that it's not a user-friendly approach since if my bundle has ASI compiled in, users won't be able to use it, right?